# How to render header or some data then whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on eCommerce website which is taking too much of time load whole webpage because of lots of images and data

How can I render some data like header first and then other like images, etc?

Comment: You should not be loading all the images on the first load, you must load only that is required in the current view/route.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code or see this voted down and closed

Comment: You may lazy load images. There are jQuery plugins like: [UNVEIL](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to load part of the website one by one. In your html code just keep whatever is necessary to show at first and then on the document being ready, call your ajax scripts to bring the data at runtime. This way user may not notice a lot of lag.